# LinQ WHERE string.Contains or string.IndexOf?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to write something that would give the same result as:

```
var result = collection.Where( o => o.Name.IndexOf( "some_string2" ) != -1 || o.Name.IndexOf( "some_string_2" ) != -1 || o.Name.IndexOf( "some_string3" ) != -1 )
```

Where the amount and values of the strings to check for (some_string_1, 2 and 3) are unknown (coming from DB), so something more generic...

I tried the following, but failed...

```
var stringsToCheck = someCommaSeparatedStrings.ToLower().Split( ',' ).ToList();
var result = collection.Where( o => stringsToCheck.Contains( o.ToLower() ) );
```

In other words, I need to retrieve all the objects from a collection which names contain some specific strings.

Comment: Is this EF or LINQ to objects?

Comment: @flq He uses the term `collection`, so probably neither.

Comment: Well, I ask because it should work if it were LINQ to objects...

Comment: Why did it fail (what is the error message)? I'm assuming you're using LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Are you wanting to test whether the `o.Name` contains a `stringToCheck`, or whether `o.Name` is equal to a `stringToCheck`?

Comment: @chamila_c, I was trying to check if `o.Name` contains some string, but I have an undetermined amount of strings to check, which is why I was trying to use .Contains().
@flq, neither.
@Servy, you're right :)
@Tejs, no error message, returned collection was just empty.
@Jonathan Wood, if you are a programmer, please read the code. And look at the answers I received, they are correct, so somehow I guess an evolved enough brain is able to understand my query...

Comment: @Seb Johnathan is actually correct.  You should have more properly explained what didn't work and why.  In my case I was able to answer because I simply ignored your attempt, looked at the problem you stated and solved that from scratch.  Had I only seen your second implementation and not the full requirements, I would have no idea what's wrong or how to fix it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
var result = collection.Where(item => stringsToCheck.Any(stringToCheck => 
    item.Name.Contains(stringToCheck)));
```

Read in English this is: give me all of the items in the collection where, of all of the strings to check one of them is a substring of the string in the collection.

Comment: Statement does not work. Gives error message Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

Comment: @SteveStaple This is a question about querying an in memory collection, not a LINQ to SQL query.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to test whether `o.Name` contains a `stringToCheck` then:

```
var result = collection.Where( o => stringsToCheck.Any(a => o.Name.Contains(a)));
```

If you only need to test for equality, then:

```
var result = collection.Where( o => stringsToCheck.Contains(o.Name));
```

Note: if you need to apply case normalisation then `ToLower()` should be applied accordingly.

Comment: Note that any time you see `Count() > 0` bells should go off, and you should be using `Any()` instead.  First, `Any` semantically represents what you mean, second, it can short circuit (end as soon as it finds one match) rather than needing to evaluate the whole query.

Comment: @Servy, yup, good call. Especially the instant return on first 'true' evaluation. Updated my post accordingly - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the collections element `o.ToLower()` i assume you must check for its name `o.Name.ToLower()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether `o.Name` contains some `string` from the `stringsToCheck`, I would suggest to use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) and build the query with `PredicateBuilder`.

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<TypeOfYourObject>();
var stringsToCheck = someCommaSeparatedStrings.ToLower().Split( ',' ).ToList();

foreach(var str in stringsToCheck)
{
     var tmp = str; 
     predicate = predicate.Or(o=> o.Name.IndexOf(tmp) != -1);
} 
resultQuery = collection.Where(predicate);
```