# LINQ to SQL to find values starting with characters from another table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I would like to retrieve a list of values from a SQL table where the records start with a prefix defined in another table.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346961/linq-where-string-contains-or-string-indexof) gives an accurate answer, but it is for EF and not Linq to SQL.
With SQL I get an error:

> Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for
>   the String.Contains method

Sample code:

```
var lookupList = dc.LookupTable.Select(p => p.Prefix);
var q = dc.Personnel
          .Where(item => lookupList
          .Any(p => item.Surname.StartsWith(p))).Select(x => x.PersonID);
```

This works with EF.  Yes, I can ToList() my collections but the tables are big and the query becomes very slow. Any suggestions on how to make it work without enumerating my objects?

Comment: The "this post" link redirects to a website asking for credentials to download something. You sure it's a correct link?

Comment: please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1703767/366064 for workaround

Comment: Apologies for the wrong link. Corrected now.

Comment: @Bizhan: your link seems to provide the correct answer. If you post as answer, I will accept and you can get the creds.

Comment: @CameronCastillo sure, I added an answer. please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part: `.Any(p => item.Surname.StartsWith(p))` gives the error:

> Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the String.Contains method

It tells you `Contains` method **does not work** with the given parameter which can only be evaluated on the server. `StartsWith` basically uses the same mechanism.
So, instead of `Contains` or `StartsWith` you should use `IndexOf` to find out whether or not the containing parameter is occured at the beginning or not:

```
.Any(p => item.Surname.IndexOf(p) == 0)
```

---

According to MSDN:

> IndexOf(T):
>
> The index of item if found in the list; otherwise, -1.

*This answer is partially taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1703767/366064).*