# Linq To SQL Performance on IndexOf

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

We are using LINQ to filter a SQL table to find records where data in a column are starting with any substring found in another table (a lookup table with a long list of prefixes).

We have tried StartsWith as per the solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346961/linq-where-string-contains-or-string-indexof) but it only works in EF.

But [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183037/linq-to-sql-to-find-values-starting-with-characters-from-another-table) did give a correct solution for LinqToSQL.

Problem is that it is very slow on large tables.  Our table with Surnames have a million records and the lookup table about 50 000.

Here is a sample of our current code. How can we increase the performance?

(All fields part of comparisons have already got indexes on)

```
var lookupList = LookupTable.Select(p => p.Prefix);
var q = from p in dc.Personnel
        where lookupList.Any(x => p.Surname.ToUpper().IndexOf(x) >= 0)
        select new 
        {
            Surname = p.Surname
        };
```

Comment: Are you sure this is anything to do with EF or Linq2SQL? Doing huge amounts of text lookups in a database like this is likely going to be horribly slow. Are you able to write a SQL query that does this in a quick enough way?

Comment: I have not tried writing my own SQL yet as this will really be a very last resort. Linq is preferred due to the advantages of maintenance etc.

Comment: You should really take a look at the generated SQL code. But apart of that `StartsWith` and `IndexOf >= 0` are not the same and can have vastly different performance impacts.

Comment: My point isn't to embed the SQL, it's to say that you can't write a SQL query that will do this in a quick manner. Text lookups are notoriously slow.

Comment: Are your prefixes always the same length? > then store the correspondingly pre-truncated value in a new indexed column of the Personnel table and compare with equality.

Comment: No, it is sadly not the same length.

Comment: Use a dictionary.  I used the class Namespace (you can replace with you class).            Dictionary<string, Namespace> dict = Namespaces.GroupBy(x => x.Prefix, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: @jdweng: Just want to check please. I've loaded the lookup values in a Dictionary as requested. How do you see joining up with that? I now have the following. Correct?  
var q = from p in Personnel
  where (dict.Any(c => p.Content.Contains(c.Key)))
  select new
  {
   Surname = p.Surname
  };

Comment: Why not : var q = Personnel.Select(p => dict[p.Surname]).ToArray();

Comment: I get a KeyNotFoundException. Looking at your suggestion it tries to find Surname in the Dictionary. It will not be there as the Dictionary only contains substrings of characters with which the surname might start with.

Comment: I tried a few options with the Dictionary, but getting out of memory errors.

Answer (score 1):

> Problem is that it is very slow on large tables

Problem is that whoever designed that did not know the basics of SQL.

IndexOf - or anything that does not start at the beginning of a string - kills sargeability. Period. Which means any index will not be used. Which means that basically you are making a table scan and on every table have to go through chars and compare them until... well. And ToUpper does or may not actually do anything - field comparison is determined on the SQL level by collation index, and unless that is "take upper/lower into account" you just have a non operation on your hand.

What you CAN do is:

- Do those on a separate connection that uses a lower transaction guarantee (Readcommitted) so you do not leave locks on the table. Standard connection is serializable, TOTALLY unsuited for lookup tables.

  - you may want to hide the table and use an index that forwards ot the table using readcommmitted for this.
- Or load them into memory ONCE then run that in parallel in memory, depends whether this is a server code.

At the end, looking IN strings is EXTREMELY work intensive and there is VERY little you can do and SQL is generally not optimized for this. This is neither an EF nor a Linq2SQL problem - pretty much as your driving license does not determine that your car is not an airplane. SQL generally does not handle this type of query decently.

Comment: Thanks. It does not fill me with hope for a quick solution, but at least our answer confirms my worst suspicions and will point me in the correct direction. Tx!

Comment: Yes, this is just a sample to make the case simple. Otherwise I might have had to explain a lot of other things too. Similar to a data warehouse where data comes from different systems and needs to be compared and filtered.